# How do I get a list of shared library filenames under Linux?

Tags: linux, libraries

Is there a GNU Linux built-in for getting a list of the filenames of shared libraries?  I have considered parsing the output of `ldconfig -p`. However, I'm not sure about consistency in output from system to system.

I am already aware that I could use `find` but given that the linker / loader has a cache of libraries and locations, it seems more efficient to use it in some way. Additionally, the paths that the linker / loader searches are the only ones I'm concerned with--i.e libraries that have been processed by `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to catch them all, there is no other choice but to do full filesystem traversals. `ldconfig` knows only about the libraries in the standard paths and the extra paths it is configured to look in (usually defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf*`). The usual suspect places where other libraries can be found are `$HOME` and `/opt`, though there is no limit, especially when people build applications themselves.

If you don't trust the output of `ldconfig -p`, you can parse its cache directly. It's binary, but using `strings` removes all the garbage (5 so /lib/ matches):

```
strings -n5 /etc/ld.so.cache
```

On my system, they both give the same results, which I verified with this quicky:

```
a=$(ldconfig -p | awk -F'> ' '{print $2}' | sort); # get them to the same format
b=$(strings -n5 /etc/ld.so.cache | sort -u); 
echo -e "$a\n$b\n$b" | sort | uniq -u
```

Which checked if any library on the `ldconfig -p` list was not mentioned in the cache. Nothing was returned.

Comment: lynxlynxlynx, I appreciate your thoughts and I understand that perspective.  I should limit the scope of my question--I'll edit for clarity.  In this case, we are concerned primarily with what `ldconfig` knows about.

Comment: I hope it is not a security measure, since you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_ADD` and probably others that can practically circumvent the original list.

Comment: You bring up a good point. This is not a security measure.  It's one approach in an effort to support some legacy scripts that depend libs that could be in one of several different locations.

Comment: Great update! Parsing the cache directly this way really helps.